# Reason why setting tensorflow's variable with small stddev

Tags: variables, tensorflow

I have a question about a reason why setting TensorFlow's variable with small `stddev`.
I guess many people do test MNIST test code from TensorFlow beginner's guide.
As following it, the first layer's weights are initiated by using `truncated_normal` with `stddev` 0.1.
And I guessed if setting it with more bigger value, then it would be the same result, which is exactly accurate. 
But although increasing epoch count, it doesn't work.
Is there anybody know this reason?

original :

```py
W_layer = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([inp.get_shape()[1].value, size],stddev=0.1), name='w_'+name)
#result : (990, 0.93000001, 0.89719999)
```

modified :

```py
W_layer = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([inp.get_shape()[1].value, size],stddev=200), name='w_'+name)
#result : (99990, 0.1, 0.098000005)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because you want to keep all the layer's variances (or standard deviations) approximately the same, and sane. It has to do with the error backpropagation step of the learning process and the activation functions used.

In order to learn the network's weights, the backpropagation step requires knowledge of the network's *gradient*, a measure of how strong each weight influences the input to reach the final output; layer's weight variance directly influences the propagation of gradients.

Say, for example, that the activation function is sigmoidal (e.g. `tf.nn.sigmoid` or `tf.nn.tanh`); this implies that all input values are squashed into a fixed output value range. For the sigmoid, it is the range `0..1`, where essentially all values `z` greater or smaller than +/- 4 are very close to one (for `z > 4`) or zero (for `z < -4`) and only values within that range tend to have some meaningful "change".

[image: Sigmoid]

Now the difference between the values `sigmoid(5)` and `sigmoid(1000)` is barely noticeable. Because of that, all very large or very small values will optimize very slowly, since their influence on the result `y = sigmoid(W*x+b)` is extremely small. Now the pre-activation value `z = W*x+b` (where `x` is the input) depends on the actual input `x` and the current weights `W`. If either of them is large, e.g. by initializing the weights with a high variance (i.e. standard deviation), the result will necessarily be (relatively) large, leading to said problem. This is also the reason why `truncated_normal` is used rather than a correct normal distribution: The latter only guarantees that *most of* the values are very close to the mean, with some less than 5% chance that this is not the case, while `truncated_normal` simply clips away every value that is too big or too small, guaranteeing that all weights are in the same range, while still being normally distributed.

To make matters worse, in a typical neural network - especially in deep learning - each network layer is followed by one or many others. If in each layer the output value range is big, the gradients will get bigger and bigger as well; this is known as the *exploding gradients* problem (a variation of the *vanishing gradients*, where gradients are getting smaller).
The reason that this is a problem is because learning starts at the very last layer and each weight is adjusted depending on how much it contributed to the error. If the gradients are indeed getting very big towards the end, the very last layer is the first one to pay a high toll for this: Its weights get adjusted very strongly - likely overcorrecting the actual problem - and then only the "remaining" error gets propagated further back, or up, the network. Here, since the last layer was already "fixed a lot" regarding the measured error, only smaller adjustments will be made. This may lead to the problem that the first layers are corrected only by a tiny bit or not at all, effectively preventing all learning there.  The same basically happens if the learning rate is too big.

Finding the best weight initialization is a topic by itself and there are somewhat more sophisticated methods such as [Xavier initialization](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.layers/initializers#xavier_initializer) or Layer-sequential unit variance, however small normally distributed values are usually simply a good guess.